# Bind click handler to dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

In my Ionic 2 app I have a template with this code:

```
<div class="body" [innerHTML]="ticket.Body | safeHtml"></div>
```

The body is HTML that is returned from a remote API. That HTML can contain images. I want to bind a "click" event handler on those images so that I can open them in an InAppBrowser when a user taps on them.

What would be the best way to do that?

Angular 4.1.3, Ionic 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Try binding an event on to the parent to capture clicked target elements.

```
// HTML file
<div class="body" [innerHTML]="ticket.Body | safeHtml" (click)="bodyDivClick($event)" >
</div>
```

```
// TS file
bodyDivClick(event) {
    // Check if the clicked target is an Image element.
    // You can also check by css class name for specific image elements.
    if (event.target && event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
        let imageElem = event.target;

        console.log('Image clicked');
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2**

You can also try using `ngFor` to loop your results (images) into view and bind an event on the image itself.

Assuming that `ticket` is a JSON parsed object retrieved from the remote API.

```
<div class="body">
    <div *ngFor="let imageUrl of ticket.images; let i = index;" class="image-container" >
        <img src="{{imageUrl}}" class="image-style" (click)="imageClick()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Most probably the first solution might work for you if you are not able to change the response of the Remote API from `html` to `JSON`/`objects` (if it's not implemented by you).

Comment: The first solution works perfectly. Thanks a lot - elegant and simple.